# Going fullscreen without stretching in an XNA game

Tags: xna, c#

I've got a 2D game that I'm working on that is in a single aspect ratio. When I switch it to fullscreen mode on my widescreen monitor it stretches. I tried using two viewports to give a black background to where the game shouldn't stretch to, but that left the game in the same size as before. I couldn't get it to fill the viewport that was supposed to hold the whole game.

How can I get it to go fullscreen without stretching and without me needing to modify every position and draw statement in the game?

Answer (score 2):

From: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/58545/358858.aspx (emphasis mine)

> There is a very simple answer to your
>   question: **your monitor is a widescreen
>   monitor, if you set a non-widescreen
>   resolution to it, it will have to
>   stretch the output to give you an image**.
>   Some graphics adapters and some
>   screens provide a '4:3 in wide' mode
>   which destretches for you.
>
> However if you want your game to
>   always look right and not be stretched
>   you have todo the following:
>
> - Render to a rendertarget instead of to the screen directly
> - Get the texture from the render target
> - Clear the screen to black
> - Start a spritebatch and render your texture at the correct aspectratio on
>     screen scale it by using an overload
>     that uses the targetRectangle, this
>     way you have automatic black borders
>     either above or on the sides.
>
> This should be be realy easy to
>   implement :)

Comment: The problem is explained above (Monitors will generally stretch out an image to make it fit in full screen). I however think the easiest solution is to just change your rendering resolution with the adapter to a support full screen resolution. I would imagine that XNA still has the render mode enumerable that you can get that information from.

Comment: Exactly, there isn't an automatic way to do this for 2D -- you need to render on something besides the screen, then render that to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set your ProjectionMatrix like so:

```
ProjectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView( MathHelper.PiOver4,
                                                        (float)Game.Window.ClientBounds.Width / (float)Game.Window.ClientBounds.Height,
                                                        1.0f,
                                                        3000.0f );
```

This will set your aspect ratio correctly, in whatever screen you're using.

Comment: projection matrix?  Isn't that just if you're using cameras?  My game is only in 2D so I'm not using a camera.